# GitLab API: How to PUT a large binary file as base64 together with other key=values

Tags: curl, gitlab, put, gitlab-api

I need to use the Gitlab API to send a **PUT**-request with curl (v.7.35.0) that holds some `key=value` parameters. Key `content` needs to be a binary file content. So I need to send it as base64, but I already fail before. However the big file content 1.2MB is the reason why I have to use stdin as curl with other syntax was complaining of too large URI / argument lists.

Took some input from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174350/curl-argument-list-too-long
. But still a bit lost with the combination of arguments in curl.

```
DATA="{
    \"author_email\": \"autoupdate-geoip@company.com\",
    \"author_name\": \"Autoupdater GeoIp\",
    \"branch\": \"${BRANCH_NAME}\",
    \"content\": \"this-should-be-file-content-of-GeoIP.dat\",
    \"commit_message\": \"Update GeoIP database\"
    \"encoding\": \"base64\"
}"

curl -X PUT -G "${GEOIP_URL}" \
    --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data-urlencode @- <<EOF
"${DATA}"
EOF
```

Common alternatives to curl would also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it to work with this:

```
base64 --wrap 0 GeoIP.dat > GeoIP.dat.base64
curl -vvvv -X PUT  \
     --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" \
     --data-urlencode "author_email=autoupdate-geoip@company.com" \
     --data-urlencode "author_name=Autoupdater GeoIP" \
     --data-urlencode "branch=${BRANCH_NAME}" \
     --data-urlencode "commit_message=Autoupdate GeoIP Database" \
     --data-urlencode "encoding=base64" \
     --data-urlencode "file_path=some/path/geoip/GeoIP.dat" \
     --data-urlencode content@GeoIP.dat.base64 \
     "${GEOIP_URL}" | python -m json.tool
```