# How to upload a large binary file to GitLab using API

Tags: curl, gitlab-api

I need to upload a large binary archive (> 1 GB) into the GitLab repository.

I would like to use [GitLab File API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#create-new-file-in-repository) to avoid cloning the already large repo just for this. (There, unfortunately, seems to be no support for Git LFS in the API yet.)

I have found an [OK answer to a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48118025/2948889), the downside is that it requires the creation of a temporary base64 encoded file. I have tried to pass

```
--data-urlencode "content@<(base64 < binary_archive.tgz)"
```

which `curl` didn’t like.

I haven’t been able to make a more efficient transfer with e.g. [`type=application/octet-stream`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) work.

What will be the way to upload the file with minimal side processing?